# Регулярное выражение для чисел и знака вопроса

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Добрый день, помогите составить регулярное выражение чтобы находило следующие случаи:

```
1243?21421?
?2135437?3426324?
312??32141?1?
```

То есть знак вопроса может находится в каком угодно месте и в каком угодно количестве.

Comment: это полные строки? в них никаких других символов не может быть?

Comment: например: `/^(\d|\?)+$/`

Comment: Чтобы не усложнять - `/^[0-9?]+$/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, я думал про `[]` но у меня как-то не очень получалось :-)

Comment: Кстати, `\d` не всегда только арабские цифры находит. В зависимости от библиотеки, может найти и [такие циферки - `۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cd%2b&i=%db%b1%db%b2%db%b3%db%b4%db%b5%db%b6%db%b7%db%b8%db%b91234567890).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[\d?]+**

```
perl -E '$a = "asdf322??223"; $a =~ /([\d?]+)/; say $1'
```